# Linear Algebra quadratic forms diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, diagonalization

I have a question that reads:

> Diagonalize the quadratic form $A(x,x) = 2x^2 - 1/2 y^2 -2xy - 4xz$ by completing the squares, and find the change of basis matrix and the new basis in which A will be diagonalized.
>
> **HINT:** The change of basis matrix is the inverse of the change of coordinates matrix.

Can someone give me the definition of "diagonalize" in this context and walk me through this problem?  I would really prefer to understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** My answer below is more than a bit disorganized; if any one cares to clean it up a bit, I welcome the effort.

---

It seems that diagonalize in this context would mean something like writing
$$
2x_1^2 - (1/2) x_1^2 -2x_1x_2 - 4x_1x_3 =
A(x,x) = x^TU^T DUx = (Ux)^TD(Ux)
$$
for some diagonal matrix $D$ and invertible matrix $U$, where $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$.

In particular, defining $y = Ux$, we should have
$$
A(x,x) = y^TDy = d_1 y_1^2 + d_2 y_2^2 + d_3 y_3 ^2
$$

---

More specifically, we have
$$
2x^2 - (1/2)y^2 -2xy - 4xz = \\
(1/2)(y^2 - 4xy + 4x^2) - 4xz =\\
(1/2)(y - 2x)^2 - 4xz =\\
(1/2)(y - 2x)^2 + [(x - z)^2 - (x+z)^2] =\\
(1/2)(y - 2x)^2 + (x - z)^2 - (x+z)^2
$$
Now, let $y = (y_1,y_2,y_3)^T$ be a coordinate vector such that
$$
\pmatrix{y_1\\y_2\\y_3} = 
\pmatrix{x_2 - 2x_1\\x_1 - x_3\\x_1 + x_3}
$$
This can be written as $y = Mx$, where
$$
M = \pmatrix{-2&1&0\\1&0&-1\\1&0&1}
$$
From before, we have
$$
A(x,x) = 2x_1^2 - (1/2)x_2^2 -2x_1x_2 - 4x_1x_3 = 
(1/2)(y_1)^2 + (y_2)^2 - (y_3)^2
$$
We now have $A(x,x) = D(Mx,Mx)$ where
$$
D(y,y) = (1/2)(y_1)^2 + (y_2)^2 - (y_3)^2
$$

Comment: How do we find this orthogonal matrix U?

Comment: See my latest edit.  Hopefully this gets you started.

Comment: I guess $U$ doesn't need to be orthogonal, in retrospect.  There is an easier (less "completing the square" based) approach to these kinds of questions using symmetric matrices

Comment: Yes, I found the matrix {{1,-1,-2}{-1,-1/2,0}{-2,0,0}} which I believe would satisfy the equation.  Does this help?

Comment: Yes, it does. Can you rewrite $A(x,x)$ using this matrix? Note that you should end up taking the inverse of a matrix in the process.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a convenient way to represent matrices on here.  But would we multiply the vectors {x,y,z} on either side of the matrix I just proposed?

EDIT:

An inverse? :S I'm sorry, I'm fairly confused now

Comment: @Arbitrationer for example, `$$\pmatrix{1&-1&-2\\-1&-1/2&0\\-2&0&0}$$` is rendered as
$$\pmatrix{1&-1&-2\\-1&-1/2&0\\-2&0&0}$$
what you're saying sounds like it could be right but it's hard to be sure of what you mean.  See [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more information.

Comment: Yeah I have that matrix I'm just unsure of how that does anything for us.  I recall diagonalizing matrices as (I believe) finding a matrix of it's Eigenvectors, say S, and, if the matrix above is called A, then the diagonalization would be

S^-1 * A * S

Comment: Oh, I see what you're doing.  That doesn't appear to be the way the question (as asked) wants you to approach the question.  I'll finish off my answer, and hopefully you'll see how it all comes together.  You could start from the diagonalization of that matrix, but that isn't doing things "by completing the square"

Comment: Thank you for your persistence in helping me to understand.  I'm going to go over what you did a few times to solidify the idea in my head.  Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: My work here is a bit less organized than usual, so feel free to ask for clarification.